# two way switch for a bulb circuit

Tags: wiring, switching

how to install a wiring where I can have two switches the two switches will turn on a bulb

I have to turn on the light if any of the switch is on and I have to turn off the light if any of the switch is turned off

can you suggest me a way to install such a mechanism thanks in advance

Comment: Environment? Voltage levels? If you are asking for household stuff, ask your local electrican.
We don't thank in advance, we thank with an accepted answer.

Comment: If you write a truth table for this you will see that it is impossible, however if you relax one implied condition it can done with something like an ex-or. See 'three way' if you are really stuck. This is kind of trick question.

Comment: For household lighting this is called a three-way switch, and requires two (or more) switches with both a normally open and normally closed contact.

Comment: What state should the light be in, if one switch is on and one is off?

Comment: Dual edge triggered T Flip-Flop? (with debouncing circuitry ofc)

Comment: @RDrast: It's a two-way switch in Europe (a "way" being a position). For more than two switches a changeover (4 terminals with cross-over) or "intermediate" switch is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to turn on the light if any of the switch is on and I have to turn off the light if any of the switch is turned off.

Your stated requirements are contradictory. If one switch is on and the other is off then, according to your requirement:

- "Turn on the light if any of the switch is on." So the light is on.
- "Turn off the light if any of the switch is turned off." So the light is off.

You need to make up your mind.

If you want a two-way lighting system then you use two changeover switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSRyhB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two-way lighting circuit using 2-way switches. (These are called 3-way switches in North America - probably because they have three wires. They only have two switch positions.)*

The circuit of Figure 1 is probably what you want but not what you asked for.

Comment: Agreed. I looked at the requirements for a few seconds and thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two single pole double throw switch as shown in schematic  [image]