# Using multiple DPDT switches to control one motor

Tags: motor, switches, dpdt

Hi I am currently working on converting a bus into a mobile dog grooming salon. My problem is the bus has an electric door and the factory wiring dont work. Right now i have a single DPDT switch to open and close the door from inside the bus but i also need a switch to open and close the door from outside the bus. What would be the best way to achieve this. TIA.

Comment: Can you add a sketch of how you have it wired with one switch?  Does it reverse polarity to change direction?

Comment: I just have it wired from power with power jumped across pins 1 and 6 and ground jumped across pins 4 and 3 with the two middle pins controlling the motor.

Answer (score 1):

For the wiring schematic, look at [two way switch for a bulb circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251960/two-way-switch-for-a-bulb-circuit). Rather than maintained contact switches, you will need switches that have a spring return to the center (off) position. For where and how to install it, that depends on what is accessible and personal preferences. If you want do do something fancy, you could consider some kind of proximity switch near adhered to a fixed window. You also need to consider locking and unlocking.

Upon further consideration, using spring-return to off switches eliminates the need for SPDT or 3-way switches. SPST switches wired in parallel would be sufficient.

If the motor must be reversed, that complicates the problem considerably. Operating the two switches simultaneously in opposite directions would cause a short circuit.

Comment: Yes im not looking for anything fancy just something functional for now. Would those switch be like a SPDT or just standard 3 way switch’s. Sorry i am new to this kind of electrical.

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Yes that is where i am running into my issue as for the door to close the motor has to tun both ways. I was thinking about using a relay system in some form to run the door but im not sure.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps two electrically-interlocked relays and two spdt, spring return to off switches. Alternatively, repair the original system. Perhaps inquire at an auto customization or repair site.